# Want to create a mask or formatting display for a file...where do I start?

Tags: grep, file-format

on my computer I have plenty of text files which I use to configure an audio device (actually a Line6 guitar multieffect HX Stomp), and these files look like the example hereunder.
So there are lots of {}, parameters in "", mostly starting with a @, for instance

> "@model" : "HD2_DistScream808"

What I would like to do is to be able to display these files with a formatting enabling to clearly read the parameters. If I use 'more name_of_the_file' then I just get a block of text which is not comfortable to read....
For instance, in the example hereunder, there is a function block called "HD2_DistScream808", with parameters:

> ```
>  "@enabled" : false,
>  "@model" : "HD2_DistScream808",
>  "@no_snapshot_bypass" : false,
>  "@path" : 0,
>  "@position" : 1,
>  "@stereo" : true,
>  "@type" : 0,
>  "Gain" : 0.520,
>  "Level" : 0.670,
>  "Tone" : 0.650
> ```

### I would like to have these info organized automatically, e.g. like

### model : "HD2_DistScream808",
Gain : 0.520,
Level : 0.670,
Tone" : 0.650

How do I start do this ?! I guess more and grep are the tools of choice

Thanks for any hint !
Vincent

Example:
{
"data" : {
"device" : 2162699,
"device_version" : 56623104,
"meta" : {
"application" : "HX Edit",
"appversion" : 56688640,
"build_sha" : "v3.50-25-g9dead52",
"modifieddate" : 1695565543,
"name" : "SAD B TRUE"
},
"tone" : {
"controller" : {
"dsp0" : {
"block2" : {
"ChVol" : {
"@controller" : 12,
"@max" : 1.0,
"@min" : 0.0,
"@snapshot_disable" : false
},
"Drive" : {
"@controller" : 12,
"@max" : 1.0,
"@min" : 0.0,
"@snapshot_disable" : false
}
}
}
},
"dsp0" : {
"block0" : {
"@enabled" : true,
"@model" : "HD2_Chorus",
"@no_snapshot_bypass" : false,
"@path" : 0,
"@position" : 0,
"@stereo" : true,
"@type" : 0,
"Depth" : 0.810,
"Level" : 0.0,
"Mix" : 0.20,
"Predelay" : 0.320,
"Speed" : 0.250,
"Spread" : 1.0,
"SyncSelect1" : 6,
"TempoSync1" : false,
"Tone" : 0.50,
"WaveShape" : 2
},
"block1" : {
"@enabled" : false,
"@model" : "HD2_DistScream808",
"@no_snapshot_bypass" : false,
"@path" : 0,
"@position" : 1,
"@stereo" : true,
"@type" : 0,
"Gain" : 0.520,
"Level" : 0.670,
"Tone" : 0.650
},

Comment: That is a coding question. I would make a perl or python script to do this, That way you can parse and manipulate the info

Comment: If your file is JSON, you could use [miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to pretty-print it. If you want help doing that, please [edit] your question to include a complete parsable example.